# My PHP script runs well from the server terminal with SSH. However, it does not run when I access the page from the browser

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, apache2

```
<html>
<body>
Hi
</body>
</html>
<?php
   class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
      function __construct() {
         $this->open('db/test.db');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db) {
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
   $db->close();
?>
```

The above code is my PHP code. The output is -

> Hi  Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /var/www/html/db.php on
>   line 7

on my browser

and

> Hi
>
> Opened database successfully

on my ssh terminal. I don't understand why.

Just as a trial, I've given all files and folders 777 access

Comment: The CLI and the webserver may use totally different configurations (or even entirely separate installations/versions) of PHP. Check the output of `phpinfo()` on the webserver and `php -i` in the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here might be with the php extension for sqlite3. You need to install it.

On ubuntu machine, you can install it:

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite3`
OR
`sudo apt install php-sqlite3`

As a best practice never set the permission to `777`.